# how to achieve push Notifications without using firebase Cloud functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

my APP Is Really Depends on push Notifications, for examples iF the app has two actors, owner, and user, if the owner posts something, the user must be notified, based on their locations and  Engagement in the app, which means the System first searches the nearest user and notify him, Notification is performed based on the location of the user, the user who is found in the nearest location is notified first, so What I want to ask you is, is it possible to achieve this without using firebase Cloud functions, Since firebase Cloud functions are NOT Free at this time. it asks me Billing account but the payment method is not available in my country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for my previous reply, I misunderstood the situation,
Also another solution besides one signal, you can use FCM on your own server, via FirebaseAdmin SDK. If you have a NodeJS server, a simple one, you can perform all firebase functions on it. In the end, it's not an absolute necessity to use cloud functions, it's just more convenient for a simple task or a few functions than spinning up your own server just for notifications. I would advise to go with this solution, and you will have access to cloud firestore via the admin SDK, you'll feel right at home.

---

Firebase cloud functions requires billing info, but you aren't charged. You have 2 MILLION free api calls per month. Then every extra 1 million calls cost less than half a dollar.

Do you know what 2 Million API invocations per month means? That's 32 THOUSAND API calls per day. If your app is generating that much traffic, trust me, you will not be worrying about these costs.

You can use OneSignal if you want, but it's more work for you, and it's outside the Firebase ecosystem.

Go with cloud functions, when you are reaching the limit of the free tier of 2Million monthly API requests, you can start looking for investors in your app.

Comment: Thank you, Brother! but I am not worrying about money, my problem is in my country there is no payment method, there is no Visa or master card in my country, I live in Ethiopia in east Africa, and also I don't have friends or relatives outside to get Visa card or master card, now I am trying to   Search friends outside my country, to get visa..... can you help me?

Comment: I am sorry to hear that and it's unfortunate that things are this way. You can go with one signal, it might need some configurations, but it's not that hard. It'll be fun learning and you can do it without cloud functions, all you need is the 'token' for the recipient, and their documentation isn't bad.

Comment: Also another solution, you can use FCM on your own server, via FirebaseAdmin SDK. If you have a NodeJS server, a simple one, you can perform all firebase functions on it. In the end, it's not an absolute necessity to use cloud functions, it's just more convenient for a simple task or a few functions. I would advise to go with this solution.

Comment: OneSignal will be easy to implement and easy to use.